# Android app timeout how to apply? when it minimized

Tags: android, database, backendless

I want to make a exam app I want to apply a feature in my app in this feature when student minimize app then exam will automatically cancelled. so they can't cheat so please tell me what will and how will I do this in Android app in adt.

Comment: You can handle the cancel logic in onStop of the Activity lifecycle method

Answer (score 1):

In your exam activity, override `onPause()` and paste `cancel exam method` before `super.onPause()`.

**Edit:** I think you need `onPause()` instead of `onStop()`. Learn more about Activity Life cycle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you minimize app, [onStop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) will called.

> Called when you are no longer visible to the user

So inside `onStop` you can cancel the example

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // cancel exam here
}
```